# Find the missing number in the matrix

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, number-sequence, missing-digits

Find the missing number, $x$, in the following matrix
$$\begin{matrix}
16 & 13 & 9\\ 
11 & 8 & 6\\ 
9 & 7 & x
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: hi there, welcome to puzzling! however, unattributed puzzles may get closed. please provide the source as soon as possible. thanks!

Comment: (Why are we assuming this is not OP's self-created content? We should assume content is original unless there's pretty good indications it isn't — such as actually finding it elsewhere, in which case posting a link to the other source would be appropriate. I don't see any of that here; did I miss something?)

Comment: Well, in this case a helpful user has pointed out in a flag that this same question appears [on brainly.in](https://brainly.in/question/9242957) where it seems to have been posted a few months ago.

Comment: I myself am trying to work on this. Can't post the real code because it is official work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> 4, as the numbers in each row decrease from left to right, and alternate between being a power of a number and not being a power of a number.

Comment: How do I hide my answer under a spoiler box?

Comment: Please see edit — the syntax is >! (both characters). Hope this helps!